# Having trouble calling a method which uses the C# Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Class

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm basically trying to call INTO the following c# method from an nunit test method:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
  public static TValue **GetOrInsertNew**<TKey, TValue>(
        this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
        TKey key) where TValue : new()
    {
        TValue value;

        if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            value = new TValue();
            dictionary[key] = value;
        }

        return value;
    }
 }
```

My problem is that I can't figure out the proper way to call this, as my C# skills are still improving...

Here's what I have so far:

```
 public static void **GetOrInsertNew**()
    {
        Dictionary<Int16, string> dict = new Dictionary<Int16, string>();
        dict.Add(01,"Nik S.");
        dict.Add(02,"Bob M.");
        dict.Add(03,"Brad M.");
        dict.Add(03,"Thomas W.");

        Int16 val = 3;
        dynamic retVal = **DictionaryExtensions.GetOrInsertNew<Int16,string>(dict, val)**;

    }
```

The error is on the final line where I call into DictionaryExtensions.GetOrInsertNew.

Error "string must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless contruct in order to use it as parameter 'TValue' in the generic type or method..."

Can someone provide insight on how to setup that call ?
thanks 
Bob

Comment: where TValue : new() string does not have a parameterless constructor.  If you want to use string the constraint has to go, otherwise use some  other type, Object maybe, to aset up your test

Answer (score 0):

As this is an extension method, you would normally call this via:

```
string value = dict.GetOrInsertNew(val);
```

However, this won't work with `string`, as there is no default parameterless constructor.

One option would be to rework your class to work more like [ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378676%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which doesn't have constraints:

```
 public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> creationFunc)
{
    TValue value;

    if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        value = creationFunc(key);
        dictionary[key] = value;
    }

    return value;
}
```

You could then call this via:

```
string retVal = dict.GetOrAdd(val, k => "Your default value here");
```